# let keyword in LINQ with complicated joining

Tags: c#, linq

**Scenario**:
I am joining 8 tables.

```
public object SomeMethodInDacLayer()
{
    var item = await
        (from item in _dbContext.SomeDbSet
         where item.SomeProperty == "1234"
         let hasPrerequisites = HasPassed(.....)
         let hasIssues = HasIssues(.....)
         select new Person()
         {
             HasPassed = hasPassed,
             HasIssues = hasIssues
         })
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return item;
}

private static bool HasPassed(.......)
{
    var result =
        from enrollment in _dbContext.SomeDbSet2
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //  Various joins and complex calculation logic 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        select hasPassed;

    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}

private static bool HasIssues(.......)
{
    var result =
        from enrollment in _dbContext.SomeDbSet3
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //  Various joins and complex calculation logic 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        select hasPassed;

    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is LINQ going to execute these let statements in parallel?
Is there any documentation available on how .NET framework executes this scenario internally?

Comment: Nope, they will be converted into SQL query(ies). Single or splitted depending on the configuration.

Comment: Usage of `HasPassed` and `HasIssues` is not convertible to the SQL. Your query will fail.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It's executing perfectly. Just want to understand the execution process.

Comment: Well, probably you have used something old, like EF 6, or EF Core 2.x. And looks like your query may have N+1 query problem.

Comment: Why do you have `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Which EF version is this? And did you check the generated queries?

Comment: There are 3 queries generated inside the editor. Can anyone tell if they are generated on a single thread?

Comment: Single thread. And probably has very poor performance.

Comment: Ok. API responds ~1s. Alternative of this?

Comment: Which ORM do you use? And which version?

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore6.0.9

Comment: Well, for each record (one in your case), EF Core executes 2 additional queries (`HasPassed` and `HasIssues`). It is executed in single thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248935/discussion-between-prateek-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).